# Accessing and Storing multiple POJO classes in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have Multiple POJO classes as type's for the main POJO class which I am using to parse the json data using Retrofit. So I provided type converters for the first level Pojo but I'm having trouble in reading the stored data because that is not in correct format.

Here is my POJO class

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry")
public class Entry implements Parcelable {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    private FeedID feedId;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private Title EntryTitle;
    @SerializedName("im:image")
    private List<Image> image;
    @SerializedName("summary")
    private Summary summary;

    public Entry(){}

    public FeedID getFeedId() {
        return feedId;
    }

    public void setFeedId(FeedID feedId) {
        this.feedId = feedId;
    }

    public Title getEntryTitle() {
        return EntryTitle;
    }

    public void setEntryTitle(Title entryTitle) {
        this.EntryTitle = entryTitle;
    }

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Summary getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(Summary summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Entry> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Entry>() {
        @Override
        public Entry createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Entry(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Entry[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Entry[size];
        }
    };

    protected Entry(Parcel in) {
        feedId = (FeedID) in.readValue(FeedID.class.getClassLoader());
        EntryTitle = (Title) in.readValue(Title.class.getClassLoader());
        if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
            image = new ArrayList<Image>();
            in.readList(image, Image.class.getClassLoader());
        } else {
            image = null;
        }
        summary = (Summary) in.readValue(Summary.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(feedId);
        dest.writeValue(EntryTitle);
        if (image == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeList(image);
        }
        dest.writeValue(summary);
    }

    public class Title implements Parcelable {
        private String label;

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public final Parcelable.Creator<Title> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Title>() {
            @Override
            public Title createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Title(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Title[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Title[size];
            }
        };

        protected Title(Parcel in) {
            label = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(label);
        }
    }

    public class Image implements Parcelable {
        private String label;

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public final Parcelable.Creator<Image> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Image>() {
            @Override
            public Image createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Image(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Image[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Image[size];
            }
        };

        protected Image(Parcel in) {
            label = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(label);
        }
    }

    public class Summary implements Parcelable {
        private String label;

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public final Parcelable.Creator<Summary> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Summary>() {
            @Override
            public Summary createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Summary(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Summary[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Summary[size];
            }
        };

        protected Summary(Parcel in) {
            label = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(label);
        }
    }

    public class FeedID implements Parcelable {

        private Attributes attributes;

        public Attributes getAttributes() {
            return attributes;
        }

        public void setAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
            this.attributes = attributes;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public final Parcelable.Creator<FeedID> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FeedID>() {
            @Override
            public FeedID createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new FeedID(in);
            }

            @Override
            public FeedID[] newArray(int size) {
                return new FeedID[size];
            }
        };

        protected FeedID(Parcel in) {
            attributes = (Attributes) in.readValue(Attributes.class.getClassLoader());
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeValue(attributes);
        }
    }

    public class Attributes implements Parcelable {

        @SerializedName("im:id")
        private String id;

        public String getIm() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setIm(String im) {
            this.id = im;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public final Parcelable.Creator<Attributes> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Attributes>() {
            @Override
            public Attributes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Attributes(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Attributes[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Attributes[size];
            }
        };

        protected Attributes(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(id);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my TypeConverter class

```
    public class RoomTypeConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(Entry.Title value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(value);
        return json;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Entry.Title toTitle(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Entry.Title>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(Entry.FeedID value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(value);
        return json;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Entry.FeedID toFeedID(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Entry.FeedID>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(Entry.Summary value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(value);
        return json;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Entry.Summary toSummary(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Entry.Summary>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(List<Entry.Image> value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(value);
        return json;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Entry.Image> toImage(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Entry.Summary>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }
}
```

Do I have to create multiple POJO's like that only for one field? Do we have any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to save a POJO you have to **define a class** for it (either inner or normal class).

But what I understand from your data schema is that you have a possibly **complex** data store server side and you want to use a **subset** of that data in your app. Your POJO can be simplified so you can create a Class called `EntryRecord` for example and define a simple setter and getter for it like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry")
public class EntryRecord {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String feedId;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private StringEntryTitle;
    @SerializedName("im:image")
    private String[] image;
    @SerializedName("summary")
    private String summary;

    public EntryRecord(Entry entry){
        //Resolve primitive values from Entry class attributes..
    }

    public Entry getEntry(){
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        //Resolve entry values from primitive ones...
        return entry ;
    }
}
```

, now all you have to do is to use this class to save and restore your data, you can event make your `DAO` **abstract** to convert your POJO before save and vice versa.

P.S: if you don't have any use for such complex Schema with so many single variable classes I really advise you to define custom **GSON** `serializer`/`deserializer` to convert the complex POJO to simplified one from the beginning; removing such a complex schema entirely from your code base.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little research I have found a annotation for which if you have multiple inner classes room will take care of it and you don't have to create any TypeConverters for it.

***@Embedded*** Can be used as an annotation on a field of an Entity or Pojo to signal that nested fields (i.e. fields of the annotated field's class) can be referenced directly in the SQL queries.

For example, if you have 2 classes:

```
    public class Coordinates {
       double latitude;
       double longitude;
   }
   public class Address {
       String street;
       @Embedded
       Coordinates coordinates;
   }
```

Room will consider latitude and longitude as if they are fields of the Address class when mapping an SQLite row to Address.

Source : [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded)